# R_Matrix_loop: Error in loop through columns

Tags: r, loops

I have two data frames 'obs' and  'sim' each with 25 columns. I want to do the following operation using for- loop

```
for(i in 2:25) {
obs<-obs[,i]
sim<-sim[,i]
plot(sim,obs)
}
```

But it gives an error 'Error in obs[, i] : incorrect number of dimensions'. I am sure both data frames are Matrix. And when I do without the loop it works (eg: obs[,2], obs[,3], and so on). I don't know what's wrong with the loop. Anyone to help?

Comment: Hard to tell. Post the code for "doing it without loop" and the output of `str(obs); str(sim)` since your description is insufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that loop you are changing the size of `obs` on every single iteration to a one dimensional object at this line:

```
obs<-obs[,i]
```

So now `obs` is just the 'ith' column of `obs` and then on your second iteration your loop barfs.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you very much @iShouldUseAName. Renaming works fine.

```
for(i in 2:25) {
obsf<-obs[,i]
simf<-sim[,i]
plot(simf,obsf)
}
```

It's a silly mistake. I should have figured it out myself. ;)